# The best way to handle serialized object from C# client in Node.js server env

Tags: c#, node.js, serialization, buffer

What's the correct/mainstream way to handle `byte arrays` sent from C# client code to Node.js server environment?

Now I'm using standard C# serialization through `BinaryWriter` (client-side) and `streambuf` npm-package (server-side).

But I'm pretty sure that there is a more straightforward/native/mainstream/efficient way to do it.

What I have to do?

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: You're sending a byte array. Why can't you just write the byte array directly to the response stream?

Comment: AFAIK there are a low level differences/considerations about some data types storing schema like booleans and floating point numbers (in other words: I'm not pretty sure if C# do serialization of data types in the manner which Node.js expects to handle).

Comment: Sorry, it sounded like you were serializing a byte array. I would suggest looking at something like JSON (if that's a reasonable solution), or for binary solutions: Google's Protocol Buffers, or perhaps something like the the MessagePack serializer.

Comment: Thank you @DiplomacyNotWar! I need to serialize data to bytes. MessagePack looks cool but I'd like to use more mainstream/standard solution :) As for gRPC -- I want just serialize data and then use WebSocket as a transport level -- gRPC is overkill solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The mainstream way to convert an object to a serialized representation would be to use a serialization framework. If you are using node.js I would assume [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) would be most appropriate. I'm not familiar with Node.js, but my understanding is that it handles json natively. See also [newtonsoft json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for another very popular library.

If you need more a more compact serialization format you might take a look at [protobuf](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) since that serializes to a binary format. It looks like there are protobuf packages available for Node.js, but again, I have no familiarity with javascript.

Using an existing serialization format tend to make it easier to share objects between different systems since there are usually libraries available for most popular formats for the most common platforms. It usually also makes compatibility easier since many formats allow some flexibility for things like optional fields. So if you find that you need to add some more data you can often do so in the confidence that it will not break existing users.